# Android LocationLister implemented in IntentService never execute the OnLocationChanged() method

Tags: android, intentservice, locationlistener

I've written an IntentService which implements the LocationListener interface. The service should send a message when OnLocationChanged() method was called at the first time.
But OnLocationChanged() is never called.
Here's my code:

```js
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
    protected Messenger mMessenger;
    protected LocationManager mLocationManager = null;

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("LocationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got starting intent: " + intent.toString());
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            Messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");

            if(mLocationManager == null) {  
            mLocationManager =  (LocationManager) MyIntentService.this
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }
            String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
            boolean gpsIsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);

            if(gpsIsEnabled) {
                Context con = MyIntentService.this;
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0,
                                                        MyIntentService.this);
            } 
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "NO GPS!");
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got Location");
        Log.i(TAG, "Got Messenger: " + mMessenger.toString() 
                    + "\nand Location Manager: " + mLocationManager.toString());

        if(mMessenger != null && mLocationManager != null){
            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = result;
            msg.obj = location;
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(MyIntentService.this);

            try { mMessenger.send(msg); } 
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception caught : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the LocationManager OK? You could try `Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: also make sure you have the correct permissions set in the manifest, and try relaxing the allowed providers to scope out the issue, ie allow network and wifi location updates etc etc and see if anything is coming through. Check the lifecycle of the Service and make sure that it's not being destroyed after onHandleIntent has been executed

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device? First check if the service is started properly... Then try by changing the distance to 1 or more in `requestLocationUpdates` call..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've written an IntentService which implements the LocationListener interface.

That is not a good idea. An `IntentService` should not do anything that lives past the `onHandleIntent()` method.

> The service should send a message when OnLocationChanged() method was called at the first time. But OnLocationChanged() is never called.

This is not surprising, as the service will be destroyed a millisecond or so after it is created, based upon your implementation.

If your objective is to have a reasonably current location at all times, try the [Little Fluffy Location Library](http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/). Or, consider my [`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to fix this for hours and don't understand why this method wasn't called. My intention was to get the Position once by the Service, so I can show a Progress Dialog in my Activity till the Service answers. Now I will realize this without a service just with a second Activity.