# Location listener works from a Service but not an IntentService

Tags: android, service, gps, location, intentservice

I have an app where I am trying to periodically get user location and send to server. I have a service attached to an `AlarmManager` which executes every minute (for testing). The service finds the user location correctly and logs out the GPS co-ords. Once there is a GPS lock I cancel the location request and stop the service. When I ask for location updates, I start a `Handler` that executes 20 seconds later, this `Handler` removes the location update and stops the `Service` in case no lock is achieved. All this works.

Below is the code that works using the `Service` class.

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager             mlocManager;
    LocationListener            mlocListener;
    NfcScannerApplication       nfcscannerapplication;
    String carerID;

    Handler endServiceHandler;
    Runnable endServiceRunnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "in onDestroy in LocationService class");
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");

        enableMenuButtonsHandler();
        endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable,20 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


            Log.e(TAG, "in TrackingService onlocationChanged and about to send lon/lat " + loc.getLongitude() + " " + loc.getLatitude());


            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
            String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
            Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingServive = " + formattedNowTime3);


            Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                if(c.moveToLast()){

                carerID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

                }
            }

             Log.e(TAG, "carer ID = " + carerID);

             mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
             Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService)");

             TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
             Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }// end of MyLocationListener


    public void enableMenuButtonsHandler() {

        endServiceHandler = new Handler();
        endServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                endService();

            }

            private void endService() {

                 mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                 Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService) from the endService handler");

                 TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                 Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService from the endService handler");

            }
        };

    }


}// end of service
```

The problem I am having is once I have a GPS lock, I want to send the long and lat co-ords to the server. I know I can use `AsyncTask` from a `Service` but I don't want to do this. I would prefer to use `IntentService` as it runs in its own background thread. This way I can make network call directly from the `IntentService`.

The following code implements the `IntentService` class but it doesn't seem to get a lock. The GPS keeps flashing on the phone indefinitely. The logging statements get as far as 'requesting location updates', then nothing after that.

Has anyone any ideas why no lock is achieved? Thanks in advance.

```
public class TrackingService extends IntentService {

   private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
   LocationManager             mlocManager;
   LocationListener            mlocListener;
   NfcScannerApplication       nfcscannerapplication;
   String carerID;

   Handler endServiceHandler;
   Runnable endServiceRunnable;

    public TrackingService() {
        super("TrackingService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

           nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
           mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
           Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");

           mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
           Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");

           enableMenuButtonsHandler();
           endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable,20 * 1000);

    }



     private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

                 @Override
                 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


                    Log.e(TAG, "in TrackingService onlocationChanged and about to send lon/lat " + loc.getLongitude() + " " + loc.getLatitude());


                     DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                     DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
                     String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
                     Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingServive = " + formattedNowTime3);


                     Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

                    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                        if(c.moveToLast()){

                        carerID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

                        }
                    }

                     Log.e(TAG, "carer ID = " + carerID);

                     mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                     Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService)");

                     TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                     Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService");

                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

             }// end of MyLocationListener


     public void enableMenuButtonsHandler() {

                endServiceHandler = new Handler();
                endServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        endService();

                    }

                    private void endService() {

                         mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                         Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService) from the endService handler");

                         TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                         Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService from the endService handler");

                    }
                };

     }

}//end of trackingService
```

[Edit1]

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager             mlocManager;
    LocationListener            mlocListener;
    NfcScannerApplication       nfcscannerapplication;
    String carerID;

    Handler endServiceHandler;
    Runnable endServiceRunnable;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");

        enableMenuButtonsHandler();
        endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable, 20 * 1000);

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "in onDestroy in LocationService class");
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);


    }








    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


            Log.e(TAG, "in TrackingService onlocationChanged and about to send lon/lat " + loc.getLongitude() + " " + loc.getLatitude());


            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
            String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
            Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingServive = " + formattedNowTime3);


            Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                if(c.moveToLast()){

                carerID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

                }
            }

             Log.e(TAG, "carer ID = " + carerID);

             mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
             Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService)");

             TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
             Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }// end of MyLocationListener


    public void enableMenuButtonsHandler() {

        endServiceHandler = new Handler();
        endServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                endService();

            }

            private void endService() {

                 mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                 Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService) from the endService handler");

                 TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                 Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService from the endService handler");

            }
        };

    }


}// end of service
```

[Edit2]

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");


            HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
            handlerThread.start();
            Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();

            Handler handler = new Handler(looper);

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener, looper);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");

        enableMenuButtonsHandler();
        endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable, 20 * 1000);

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

[Edit3]

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager             mlocManager;
    LocationListener            mlocListener;
    NfcScannerApplication       nfcscannerapplication;
    String carerID;

    Handler endServiceHandler;
    Runnable endServiceRunnable;
    HandlerThread handlerThread;
    Looper looper;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");


            Log.e(TAG, "creating handlerthread and looper");
            handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
            handlerThread.start();
            looper = handlerThread.getLooper();





        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener, looper);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");

        enableMenuButtonsHandler();
        endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable, 20 * 1000);

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "in onDestroy in LocationService class");
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);


    }







    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


            Log.e(TAG, "in TrackingService onlocationChanged and about to send lon/lat " + loc.getLongitude() + " " + loc.getLatitude());


            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
            String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
            Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingServive = " + formattedNowTime3);


            Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                if(c.moveToLast()){

                carerID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

                }
            }

             Log.e(TAG, "carer ID = " + carerID);

             nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.sendCarerLocation(carerID, formattedNowTime3, String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));



             Log.e(TAG, "quiting handlerthread");
             handlerThread.quit();

             mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
             Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService)");

             TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
             Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }// end of MyLocationListener


    public void enableMenuButtonsHandler() {

        endServiceHandler = new Handler();
        endServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                endService();

            }

            private void endService() {

                 mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                 Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService) from the endService handler");

                 TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                 Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService from the endService handler");

                 Log.e(TAG, "quiting handlerthread from the endService handler");
                 handlerThread.quit();

            }
        };

    }


}// end of service
```

Comment: Use Service only... IntentService destroyed after `onHandleIntent` done.

Comment: have you got any error . If yes than provide the lagcat

Comment: @AM There are no errors. It gets as far as requesting location updates in the onHandleIntent code.... then nothing.

Comment: @PankajKumar so there is no way of keep onHandleIntent alive while the gps finds a lock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android LocationLister implemented in IntentService never execute the OnLocationChanged() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319466/android-locationlister-implemented-in-intentservice-never-execute-the-onlocation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Pankaj Kumar notes, an `IntentService` is not an appropriate solution for cases where the work to be done is intrinsically asynchronous. Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, your service is destroyed.

Use a regular `Service`, register for locations in `onStartCommand()`, using a `HandlerThread` for processing the results (so you can pass its `Looper` into `requestLocationUpdates()`). Once your location is received, or a suitable timeout is reached, do your work and call `stopSelf()` on the service to shut it down.

Comment: That for your response. I've edited the question [Edit1]. I've changed the code back to using a Service and overridden onStartCommand as you suggested. Could you explain and expand a little about the handlerThread, looper and passing into requestlocationUpdates. I'm not too sure what you mean there. Thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper) Using a `requestLocationUpdates()` variant that takes a `Looper` allows you to receive the `LocationListener` callbacks on a `HandlerThread` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html). This gives you the background thread you want for your work.

Comment: I've edited post again [edit2]. Would you mind having a look at it, i've amended the onStartCommand method. I've created a HandlerThread and started it. I've then created a looper from the handlerThread and passed it to the  requestLocationUpdates() which takes a looper param. I'm still a bit lost here. The documentation you sent me before says i can get a handler from the looper but i'm not sure what to do from here and how to create the background thread you mentioned where i can pass the long and lat to a network call. would you mind elaborating a little further please. thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: "how to create the background thread you mentioned" -- you already did create and start the `HandlerThread`. "where i can pass the long and lat to a network call" -- that goes in `onLocationChanged()`. When you are done with the network I/O, you can `quit()` the `HandlerThread` and `stopSelf()` the service to clean up, much in the way an `IntentService` does under the covers.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. I've posted the code as it stands now.(edit3) I think i've done how you've described? I'd like to know a little more about how this all works. I have used requestLocationUpdates() before and called it from the main thread without a looper. I have looked up about Service and it doesn't run in its own thread, so i presume it runs in the main thread. So why do i need a looper? could you explain briefly the mechanism involved here with the main thread, service, handlerthread, looper and how they interact with each other. Thanks for your time so far. Matt

Comment: @turtleboy: "So why do i need a looper?" -- you need a background thread for the network I/O, if you want your app to run without a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Android 4.0+. You may as well have the `LocationListener` callbacks delivered on that thread. You *could* use the non-`Looper` flavor of `requestLocationUpdates()`, but then you are called with `onLocationChanged()` on the main application thread. You are welcome to handle the threading in some other fashion at that point (spawn a thread, post a message to a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, etc.). The `HandlerThread` is just one option.